# Connect to bluetooth device from command line

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

**Background:** I'm using my bluetooth headset as audio output. I managed to get it working by the long list of instructions on [BluetoothHeadset community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothHeadset), and I have automated the process of activating the headset as default audio output into a script, thanks to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line).

However, since I use the bluetooth headset with both my phone and computer (and the headset doesn't support two input connections) in order for the phone not to "steal" the connection when handset is turned on, I force the headset into a discovery mode when connecting to the computer (phone gets to connect to it automatically).

So even though the headset is paired ok and would in "normal" scenario autoconnect, I have to always use the little bluetooth icon in the notification area to actually connect to my device (see screenshot).

**What I want to avoid:** This GUI for connecting to a *known and paired* bluetooth device:

[image: Connecting to Bluetooth headset using icon]

**What I want instead:** I'd want to make the bluetooth do exactly what the clicking the connect item in the GUI does, only by using command line. I want to use command line so I can make a single keypress shortcut for the action, and would't need to navigate the GUI every time I want to establish a connection to the device.

**The question:** How can I attempt to connect to a *specific, known and paired* bluetooth device *from command line?*

Further question: How do I tell if the connection was successful or not?

Comment: What tray tool is that? is it Blueman Manager tray icon? [Should Blueman manager tray applet list paired bluetooth devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1154073/925128)

Answer (score 13):

#### Bluetooth daemon

In the default installation a daemon (**bluetoothd**) runs in the background (run from the file `/etc/init.d/bluetooth`). This daemon takes care on recognizing and connecting to known bluetooth devices and may be cofigured with configuration files in `/etc/bluetooth`. For autoconneting a headset the following line in `audio.conf` should be uncommented (remove `#`):

```
AutoConnect=true
```

To restart the daemon type `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`.

<sub>**Remark:** Using the command line tool `sudo hcitool cc <MAC-Adress>` did not lead to a stable connection to a known device in the test environment here when the daemon was running.</sub>

---

#### DBus

In order to connect a disconnected but physically present and paired headset we can use [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) from a script. Here's an example in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Toggles headset connection

import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop()
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)

#Get dbus interface for headset
manager = bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/')
iface_m = dbus.Interface(manager, 'org.bluez.Manager')
adapterPath = iface_m.DefaultAdapter()
adapter = bus.get_object('org.bluez', adapterPath)
iface_a = dbus.Interface(adapter, 'org.bluez.Adapter')
devicePath = iface_a.ListDevices()[0]  # assuming first device
device = bus.get_object('org.bluez', devicePath)
iface_h = dbus.Interface(device, 'org.bluez.Headset')

#Check state of connection
connected = iface_h.IsConnected()
print 'Toggling connection. Please wait'
# toggle connection
if not connected:
    try:
        iface_h.Connect()
        print 'Connecting: ', devicePath
    except:
        print 'Device not found'
else:
    iface_h.Disconnect()
    print 'Disconnecting: ', devicePath
```

In case we have more than one Bluetooth device we will have to adapt the `devicePath` appropriately, of course. The example above will connect a `Headset`. Change the interface to a different protocol for any other service (e.g. `AudioSink`).

---

#### Pulseaudio

If you know the MAC adress of your Bluetooth device you can connect it as an output sink for pulseaudio by:

```
pacmd set-default-sink bluez_sink.xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx
```

Where xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx is the MAC address (replace ':' by '_' for pulseaudio to recognize it).

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8409/autoconnecting-bluetooth-devices/8428#8428) for more details.

Comment: I do know the address, and I replaced the xx with it. I only get `Sink bluez_sink.xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx does not exist.` Tried both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Yes, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is isntalle. No, nothing matching `bt` or `blue` is listed in `pacmd list-sinks`. (It reports only 1 sink available.)

Comment: So it's not recognized. This is a prerequisite to be able to connect by commandline. Try restarting BT or try restarting pulsaudio. I've not yet found out why it's sometimes not detetcted.

Comment: Huh? So it can be in a state that it's possible to connect from GUI, but not from CLI?

Comment: Hm, there might be a misunderstanding here. The sink *does* appear in `pacmd list-sinks` after I've connected to the bluetooth headset via the bluetooth icon GUI. What I need is a way to establish that bluetooth connection.

Comment: It **should** connect automatically at the Bluez level (but does not always). Audio sink however is not connected automatically.

Comment: @Takkat Oh, yes, good point. My bad! I'm using the headset in discovery more, so it won't autoconnect. I edited the question to reflect this. Sorry for leading you down to a wrong path.

Comment: @Ilari Kajaste: np - maybe my answers helps in other aspects ;)

Comment: @Ilari Kajast: did some testing with hcitool with little success. Hope to give you some hints where to play with - see edit.

Comment: `sudo hcitool cc MAC` didn't work for me either. I'll try to play around it a bit more, but at least on first read I didn't find any option for hcitool that would fit my case.

Comment: This script looked promising but I guess it is out of date now, the IsConnected attr isn't there for me resulting in: `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "IsConnected" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Headset" doesn't exist`

Comment: @wim: thank you for pointing to this. What Bluez version are we talking about?

Comment: @wim: Present Bluetooth implementations (Bluez vers. 4.101 is in 14.04 LTS) still support method `IsConnected()`. Just tested it and it still works as expected. In later Bluez >= 5.0 you may want to use method `State()` instead. Please also note that the script above is an example only. It will **not** let you choose of your BT devices. In case you have more than one device please give the appropriate device path for connecting (e.g. `devicePath = iface_a.ListDevices()[1]` (or higher). Hope this helps.

Comment: `dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` == `Version: 4.101-0ubuntu8b1`

Comment: Sorry, the attr is "there" (dynamic.. it's a `dbus.proxies._ProxyMethod`), but I get the exception when I call it.  I am picking the correct device from the devicelist.

Comment: I was able to get your script working `AudioSink` in place of `Headset`.  PEBKAC  :)

Comment: Ah yeah ;) In case you do not connect as `Headset` dbus can't find it... Nice you got is sorted out, will edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: Hey @Takkat, I have slightly modified your script to select device by name. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/hyOzd/53748c81eaa73f1855ef . Note that, this version of script connects to an "AudioSink" which can be easily changed to "Headset".

Answer (score 11):

After trying some of the above (scripts didn't work for me) I found the following solution.

First find out the MAC-Adress of the device you want to connect to

```
bluetoothctl
```

this will enter a shell and list all available devices with adress.  ("quit" to exit the shell & get back to prompt)

Then connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX bluetooth device :

```
echo -e 'connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' | bluetoothctl
```

to disconnect

```
echo -e 'disconnect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' | bluetoothctl
```

been searching for this quite a while - nothing seemed to work, felt so relieved when I found out. Thought others might want to know about it, too. :))

Comment: I get `~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[UE BOOM 2]#` . Then `disconnect "UE BOOM 2"
Device UE BOOM 2 not available`.

Comment: @cipricus @user3140225 Could you post the output of 

 `bluetoothctl` ? 

You need to feed the commands with the MAC-adress of the device - which is the combination of HEX Values in the format XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, where X is either a letter or a number.

Comment: I can see the MAC as said [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165197/341192). Then, trying `echo -e 'connect CC:AF:78:AF:59:03' | bluetoothctl` I get : `Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect CC:AF:78:AF:59:03
Device CC:AF:78:AF:59:03 not available`

Comment: @cipiricus did you check whether your device is paired ? maybe try unpair, delete device and then pair again. hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks Joseph, exactly what I needed... (Here's what I came up with, to reconnect my Amazon 'echo plus' )

`echo "connect $(bluetoothctl devices | grep -i "echo plus" | awk '{print $2}')" | bluetoothctl`

(command results in the string, `connect 38:F7:3D:9B:6D:89` being piped to the `bluetoothctl` command.)

Comment: There is no need for echo. You can do `bluetoothctl <command>` directly in terminal.

Just do `bluetoothctl paired-devices` if your device is already pared to see its mac address. Then `bluetoothctl connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` to connect.

Answer (score 6):

I use this script to connect my Bluetooth Audio Device.  If your headset is already paired, you should be able to connect your headset in the same way using **org.bluez.Headset.Connect/Disconnect** in place of **org.bluez.Audiosink.Connect/Disconnect**.

```
#!/bin/bash

MAC_ADD="C8:84:47:10:11:CD"

MAC_ADD="dev_${MAC_ADD//:/_}"
BT_ADAPTER=`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez / \
org.bluez.Manager.DefaultAdapter|awk '/object path/ {print $3}'`

BT_ADAPTER="${BT_ADAPTER//\"/}/$MAC_ADD"
echo "Connecting to $BT_ADAPTER..."

if [ "$1" == "on" ]; then
    dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.bluez $BT_ADAPTER org.bluez.AudioSink.Connect
elif [ "$1" == "off" ]; then
    dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.bluez $BT_ADAPTER org.bluez.AudioSink.Disconnect
fi
```

HTH!

Comment: this worked for me too on `16.04`, thank you! others, do not forget to pass `on` option to the script!

Comment: Looked good, but alas, does not work:

$ speaker on
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "DefaultAdapter" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist

Connecting to /dev_30_21_26_69_51_DE...
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "Connect" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.AudioSink" doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

I use [i3](https://i3wm.org/) as a window manager so I do not have the bluetooth tray icon available. For some reason the check button in unity settings is not sensitive and so I need a way to do this from time to time when my headphones don't connect.

[image]

It seems that `bluez` has [changed their dbus API](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/). The answer utilizing `org.bluez.Manager` no longer appears to work. Instead, it is recommended to use `ObjectManager`.

Here is an updated python script which will connect the first unconnected bluetooth headset that it finds (presumably the list includes all paired devices?):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Toggles headset connection

from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def find_headset(bus):
  manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                           "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager")
  objects = manager.GetManagedObjects()

  for path, ifaces in objects.items():
    if ("org.bluez.Device1" in ifaces and
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" in ifaces):
      iprops = dbus.Interface(
          bus.get_object("org.bluez", path),
          "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
      props = iprops.GetAll("org.bluez.Device1")
      # Looking for a headset. Could also match on other properties like
      # "Name". See bluez docs for whats available.
      if props.get("Class") == 0x240404:
        if props.get("Connected"):
          print("Found headset {} ({}) but it is already connected"
                .format(props.get("Name"), props.get("Address")))
          continue
        return path

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop()
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
hpath = find_headset(bus)

if hpath:
  adapter = dbus.Interface(
      bus.get_object("org.bluez", hpath), "org.bluez.Device1")
  adapter.Connect()
```

this example, like the other example on this thread, uses the `dbus` python package. On ubuntu 16.04 I installed this through `apt-get install python-dbus`.

If you wish to match other criteria, [this document](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/blob/master/v1/modules/ble/deps/linux/dbus-bluez/xml/org.bluez.Device1.xml) appears to show a list of properties that can be queried over dbus.

I have this script saved in `~/.local/bin/bt-connect-headset` which is on my `PATH` so I can execute it from the i3 launcher. Make it executable (`chmod +x bt-connect-headset`) if you plan to use it as a command.

This script has only been tested on an up-to-date ubuntu 16.04 as of 09/28/2018.

Comment: Used your script on Ubuntu 18.10.  Thanks!

Comment: Super, this worked for me in Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. However, I used a device class of `2360344` instead of `0x240404`.

Comment: works as such in Mint Xfce 19.2. I'm sure it works in Xubuntu. - What about a script to disconnect the bluetooth ?

Comment: @cipricus That is correct, and is already mentioned in the answer. There's a link in the answer on how to match other criteria if you need something more advanced (like matching a device of a particular name). That link also includes a list of methods available on this interface. To disconnect, my guess is use the `Disconnect()` method. I haven't tried it, but it's probably a safe bet ;).

Comment: I was wrong. I thought it never goes beyond the first in the list of paired devices, but it does. I might have also missed the fact that you say `first unconnected bluetooth headset `: will it always use the *headset* (if powered) before other device like bluetooth speakers (no matter the position in the list)? That's what happens in my case. -- Also, in order to disconnect I cannot do it by just changing the last line to `adapter.Disconnect()`.)

Comment: Also, an odd thing that happens is that if the headset is first in the paired list, I cannot connect to the speakers, even if they are powered on and the headset is not.  -- So, to make it all work: speakers always first paired, headset always shut off in case the other device is needed :))

Comment: The find_headset function didn't work for me, but if you know you're bluetooth device MAC then you can just add a line `hpath="/org/bluez/hci0/dev_**_**_**_**_**_**"` replacing the stars with your MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

In my `~/.aliases` I have

```
# Bluetooth Headphones
export WH1000XM4="88:C9:E8:3A:B4:32"
alias headon="bluetoothctl connect $WH1000XM4"
alias headoff="bluetoothctl disconnect $WH1000XM4"
alias headreset="bluetoothctl power off && bluetoothctl power on"
```

Change the MAC Address to match your device. I only chose that variable name since it matches the model number of the device.  To expose your MAC addresses try `bluetoothctl devices`.

Thus I can connect and disconnect my headphones with `headon` and `headoff`.

I need the `headreset` because sometimes I turn off the headphones without disconnecting them first, and it doesn't like that (won't reconnect); but power cycling bluetooth off/on will fix that.