# Reconnect to a previously paired bluetooth mouse from command line

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse which controls my laptop.  Every time I restart the laptop (several times a day), I have to go to the bluetooth applet, find 'Bluetooth Laser travel mouse', and then click 'connect'.  It connects almost instantly after pressing that.

Is there any way I can do that from the command line, so that I could make it a script and assign it a shortcut key?

(I have read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48001/connect-to-bluetooth-device-from-command-line) but it specifically pertains to audio.)

Comment: Through nothing I did (it must have been an update), it now connects automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try instructions on [Connect Devices At Startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup#Connect_Devices_at_Startup) wiki page