# Error while connecting A2DP device, Bluetooth BlueZ Dbus Exception Ubuntu12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, dbus

I'm unable to connect a A2DP Bluetooth Speaker in Ubuntu 12.04LTS. IBM Thinkpad R52. Broadcom Integrated Bluetooth IV.

- bluez packages installed and up-to-date
- pulsaudio installed and up-to-date
- $ dmesg|grep -i bluetooth

  - [   38.360678] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
  - [   38.360743] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  - [   38.360746] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  - [   38.360748] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  - [   38.360754] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  - [   38.367929] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
  - [   39.085152] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
  - [   40.586671] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  - [   40.586674] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  - [   40.606596] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
  - [   40.606603] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
  - [   40.606606] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
- $ hciconfig

  - hci0:
  - Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
  - BD Address: 00:0E:9B:DD:29:F6  ACL MTU: 377:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
  - UP RUNNING PSCAN
  - RX bytes:1569 acl:0 sco:0 events:105 errors:0
  - TX bytes:849 acl:0 sco:0 commands:54 errors:0

**ERRORS:**

- $ bluez-test-audio connect 00:0C:8A:96:D9:19

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-audio", line 40, in

```
audio.Connect()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in **call**

```
return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in **call**

```
**keywords)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking

```
message, timeout)
```

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.Failed: Connect Failed"

- $ bluez-simple-agent 00:0C:8A:96:D9:19

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 102, in

```
path = manager.FindAdapter(args[0])
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in **call**

```
return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in **call**

```
**keywords)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking

```
message, timeout)
```

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter

---

**Update #1**

Having tried blueman (the graphical user interface for bluetooth), I was able to shortly pair the A2DP device, but then

- dmsg | grep -i bluetooth

  [  257.824085] Bluetooth: hci0 link tx timeout
  [  257.824100] Bluetooth: hci0 killing stalled connection 00:0C:8A:96:D9:19
  [  257.824403] Bluetooth: hci0 link tx timeout
  [  257.824413] Bluetooth: hci0 killing stalled connection 00:0C:8A:96:D9:19

so pairing finally failed. Consequently, no link even with DBus possible.

Comment: bluez-test-audio always terminates with a python exception whenever it can not find or see a device. There are some bug reports on that already: [bug #1220378](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1220378)
   [Bug +1227584](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1227584). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/48001/connect-to-bluetooth-device-from-command-line to directly connect via dbus. Bugs should be reported/subscribed at Launchpad - they are off topic here.