# Bluetooth speaker via ALSA

Tags: bluetooth, alsa

I have Lubuntu 14.10 so I run ALSA instead of PulseAudio **and I am not about to change it**. `blueman-manager` lets me detect my speaker as headphones but choosing `Setup-Audio Receiver(A2DP)` results in error `The device has been successfully added but playback is impossible` (nearly translated). Launching this manager from console complements error mentioned above with [this output](http://pastebin.com/ErZPmWB4). I googled the problem around, but most of the information I found felt *very, very outdated*. So I thought that it would be safer to re-raise the issue here. Searching for `bluetooth` in Synaptic results in [image: these packages] Everything was here before, I only tried to install bluez-alsa, but it didn't change anything. Before going any further and randomly trying advices from those suspicious obsolete guides I halted and I'm here, waiting for your solutions

UPD: I looked into similar questions and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/260282/261247) script which seemed simple and comprehensible. It printed same error that GUI applet did

```
mekkanizer@N76VB:~$ ./калонка.sh on
Connecting to /org/bluez/7563/hci0/dev_CC_C5_0A_62_E8_43...
Error org.bluez.Error.Failed: Stream setup failed
```

UPD2: Installed an additional pile of useless packages (screenshot updated), still no effect

Comment: @op - did you have any luck with this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: @eddiewould nope dude. No luck at all. I have also realized that I have no idea how to distribute audio outputs between connected devices withOUT pulseaudio so I finally gave up and installed bluez/pulseaudio_bluetooth packages and lived happily ever after

Answer (score -1):

Seems every laptop I wanted to connect to headphones using bluetooth I had to `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and then redo the pairing to get the headphones to work

Comment: I do not use PulseAudio, so the pactl (which is actuallly PulseAudioConTroL) is irrelevant for me