# Shouldn't Blueman manager tray applet list paired bluetooth devices (with option to connect)?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, xfce, panel, system-tray

Using Bluetooth Manager to administer bluetooth devices (run as `blueman-manager`, from `blueman` package), all works fine, only I want a panel applet/plugin in order to connect/disconnect more easily paired/associated devices.

The paired devices are listed when running Bluetooth Manager:

[image]

When they are not connected automatically I find that interface rather heavy, especially when using multiple devices and having to do that multiple times.

**I would like to have a "connect" option in the tray icon for the paired devices.**

In my case I only see this (no devices listed, I have to press "Devices" in order to open the above window):

[image]

I think they should be listed there, because [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/48001/925128) I have found an image showing exactly what I want:

[image]

That post is old, so I'm not sure it is the same tool. Is it?

---

(My `blueman` version is 2.0.5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the answer required, relating to **using** `blueman`, but gives an **alternative to `blueman`**, as a solution to the more general problem that `blueman` didn't solve: *"I would like to have a "connect" option in the tray icon for the paired devices."*

That is provided by the 1.2.9 version of [`blueberry`](https://github.com/linuxmint/blueberry), the Linux Mint configuration tool for bluetooth, available in Linux Mint 19.2. I have tested it in the Xfce version ([New features in Linux Mint 19.2 Xfce](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tina_xfce_whatsnew.php), under *XApps improvements*: "*The Blueberry systray menu now lets you connect or disconnect paired devices with a click of the mouse*". The same is said for the Mate and Cinnamon versions).

Right-clicking the tray icon shows the menu:

[image]

I am not sure if/when blueberry 1.2.9 is/will be available in the very Ubuntu repos, and for the moment I can only find as deb to download the version 1.2.5, but [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon) provides the 1.2.9 version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/cinnamon
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blueberry
```

---

Another solution would be a panel launcher to connect, for example by running [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079342/925128) script, which will connect the first unconnected bluetooth ***headset*** that it finds.

After saving the script and making it executable, create a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` to run that script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Bluetooth-connect
Comment=
Exec=sh -c '/path/to/script'
Icon=preferences-system-bluetooth-inactive
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

Then, add 'Bluetooth-connect' as a launcher to the Xfce panel. (That `.desktop` file can be used differently in other desktops of course. It can also be found by search & launch tools like Synapse, WhiskerMenu, etc.)