# Controlling multiple audio outputs volume?

Tags: 11.10, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a little Bluetooth audio receiver, which I use to play music through my stereo.
Every time I power it on, all audio automatically switchs to it, but ALSA seems not to "know" it, so volume keys keep corresponding to internal audio. It's not a major problem, I enter to audio settings, and select the correct device. (I filled a bug about this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/906298))

I use PulseAudio volume control to select which apps play sounds through which audio output device (BT or Internal Audio).
The point is that I have to configure it every time I power on the receiver.
Is there a way to permanently set certain apps to play sounds via specific audio devices?
For example: chromium-browser to internal audio, and banshee to BT?

Another quick question, is there a way to match volume keys to control the volume of the audio device that the focused app is playing sounds through?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth devices are recognized in PulseAudio as soon as they are present.

However connection needs to be made manually in **audio settings**. There is a GUI that allows one-click connection to BT devices ([stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip)).

[This answer can show an example of python script that may be modified to suit your needs](https://askubuntu.com/a/8428/46312)

thanks to Tkkat