# Shortcuts volume specific output

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control

Ubuntu 15.04.
I have multiple audio outputs, all correctly recognised and shown by Pulseaudio.

Through `pavucontrol` GUI I can individually change the volumes of all the outputs.

The volume shortcuts only change the volume of the primary (internal) output.

I usually redirect Music on Bluetooth and I would like to have different schortcuts to change its volume.

Does anyone know which (terminal?) command should I use to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Davide

PS: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89104/controlling-multiple-audio-outputs-volume) addresses many questions, and one of them is similar. Though it is not exactly the same (I would like to not have to raise Rhythmbox every time that I want to change the volume), it was for a very old version of Ubuntu/Pulseaudio and it was not answered, so I believe that this is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line tools for pulseaudio allow adjusting the volume of a defined sink:

```
pactl set-sink-volume <name|index> <volume>
```

To find the sinks in use for their `<name>` or `<index>` (any of both will work), and to display the present volume we can issue:

```
pactl list sinks
```

The `<volume>` can take any value from `0 %` (or `0`) to `100%` (or `65536`).

Even [higher values are accepted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219739/adjust-max-possible-volume-in-pulseaudio) for volumes above the maximum but this may lead to heavy distortions from clipping.

Any of these commands can be attached as is to a keyboard shortcut but in case we need a step-wise increase/decrease volume key combination we'd have to use the following syntax:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume <name|index> <+|-fraction>
```

e.g.

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +10% ## increases volume of sink 0 by 10%
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 -10% ## decreases volume of sink 0 by 10%
```

Note that by increasing the volume this way nothing stops us to increase above 100%. Decreasing will stop at `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works! :D Do you know if there is a way to make it go up just to 100% and no more?