# Autoconnecting to bluetooth device on startup and autochanging audio output

Tags: 12.10, sound, configuration, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I use ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. Every time I turn my computer on, I have to manually connect to my bluetooth speakers and change audio output to bluetooth device.

I've found this question: [Autoconnecting Bluetooth Devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8409/autoconnecting-bluetooth-devices?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Adding a following line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` doesn't help.

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

I also installed [stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip), but it says I don't have a bluetooth device.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatization?

Comment: Doesn't work in ubuntu 16.04.
Check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/922072/autoconnect-to-a-bluetooth-speaker-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Important note:** due to changes in the d-bus protocol introduced with Bluez5 bt-autoconnect <= 0.2.2 will at present only work with Bluez4.

### [bt-autoconnect](https://launchpad.net/bt-autoconnect)

There is a python tool bt-autoconnect designed to connect to an existing audio headset as soon as it becomes available. This is useful in case we do not want to load the pulseaudio `module-switch-on-connect` in our `default.pa` (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8409/autoconnecting-bluetooth-devices)).

It will also connect a known device with the Bluetooth adapter (disable this if you want to connect manually), and it will be able to switch the audio sink to the Bluetooth sink without interrupting playback of an audio stream.

[image]

In case only one Bluetooth audio device is registered in Bluez settings we can choose *"Auto"* to autodetect this device. If we had paired more than one device we may need to specify the device by its MAC. If we do not specify the MAC bt-autoconnect will take the first device in the list which may not be the one we want.

If we choose to add bt-autoconnect to the Startup Applications it will start at login minimized to its Application Indicator only

In the Application Indicator menu we are able to switch between HSP (low quality telephony) profile with headset microphone enabled, or A2DP high quality audio profile where the microphone will not be available, provided this is supported by our headset.

[image]

Comment: Woorrrksssssssss

Comment: does not work on Linux Mint 17

Comment: @Suzana_K: thanks for the notice. See edit for reason.

Answer (score 0):

For all those having problems with `bt-autoconnect` because it does not support *Bluez5*, here is my workaround:

1. I added `module-switch-on-connect` to the pulseaudio modules.
2. I paired my stereo with my laptop using the GUI
3. I added the following to my startup and wakeup scripts (my stereo's bluetooth is usually on when I wakeup or start my computer):

   > ```
   > rfkill unblock bluetooth
   > bluez-test-audio connect MAC-ADDRESS
   > ```

Comment: In case you didn't know, Mint is based on Ubuntu and even has a tag on this site.

Comment: In case you don't know Mint is off-topic at this site. http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The Mint tag is a warning that this type of questions should NOT be asked here.

Comment: _Bluez_ is not Linux Mint specific.